# how to read the values of the clicked buttons tow?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid-view and in one column, I  added buttons with every row that it is creating a button. What I need now is, if someone clicks on that button I need to get the field of that corresponding row. I have searched for the solution but  i can't find out how to do it ?

*

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="brandname" HeaderText="brandname" SortExpression="brandname" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="info" HeaderText="info" SortExpression="info" />
                        <asp:ButtonField DataTextField="brandname" HeaderText="brandname" ButtonType="Button"/>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [brand_tbl] WHERE [Id] = @original_Id AND (([brandname] = @original_brandname) OR ([brandname] IS NULL AND @original_brandname IS NULL)) AND (([info] = @original_info) OR ([info] IS NULL AND @original_info IS NULL))" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [brand_tbl] ([brandname], [info]) VALUES (@brandname, @info)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [brand_tbl]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [brand_tbl] SET [brandname] = @brandname, [info] = @info WHERE [Id] = @original_Id AND (([brandname] = @original_brandname) OR ([brandname] IS NULL AND @original_brandname IS NULL)) AND (([info] = @original_info) OR ([info] IS NULL AND @original_info IS NULL))">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_brandname" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_info" Type="String" />
                    </DeleteParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="brandname" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="info" Type="String" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="brandname" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="info" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_brandname" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_info" Type="String" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
*
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void gView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs  e)
{
DataRowView rowView= (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;


    if (rowView["ColumnId"] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        var val =rowView["ColumnId"];

    }

}
```

// you can also do like this

```
void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   //Check if it's the right CommandName... 
  if(e.CommandName=="Add")
   {
     // do code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define `DataKeyNames` on `GridView`, follow this:
[DataKeyNames in GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23833/DataKeyNames)