# how to get the deleted rows id in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

While I delete one row in delete event, I want to have the brandid from the `GridView`.

How can I do this?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="brandname" HeaderText="brandname" SortExpression="brandname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="info" HeaderText="info" SortExpression="info" />
        <asp:ButtonField DataTextField="brandname" HeaderText="brandname" ButtonType="Button"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="brandid" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [brand_tbl] WHERE [Id] = @original_Id AND (([brandname] = @original_brandname) OR ([brandname] IS NULL AND @original_brandname IS NULL)) AND (([info] = @original_info) OR ([info] IS NULL AND @original_info IS NULL))" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [brand_tbl] ([brandname], [info]) VALUES (@brandname, @info)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [brand_tbl]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [brand_tbl] SET [brandname] = @brandname, [info] = @info WHERE [Id] = @original_Id AND (([brandname] = @original_brandname) OR ([brandname] IS NULL AND @original_brandname IS NULL)) AND (([info] = @original_info) OR ([info] IS NULL AND @original_info IS NULL))">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_brandname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_info" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="brandname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="info" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="brandname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="info" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_brandname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_info" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read the values of the clicked buttons tow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524424/how-to-read-the-values-of-the-clicked-buttons-tow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your RowDeleted event, you just need to grab `e.Keys["Id"].ToString()` to have the value of the brand ID.  This works because you have defined "Id" as your datakeynames value for the GridView already.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleted (Object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    string brandId = e.Keys["Id"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.while i used the same method

Comment: My mistake, @BorshonAeolusSaydur.  It should be e.Keys["Id"].ToString().  I've updated the answer, could you try again?  "Id" goes into the Keys collection, rather than the Values collection, because it is part of the DataKeyNames property.

Answer (score 0):

pls check this into your code

**e. rowindex show to id of the row in the deleted event**